# How to retry a failed service-task by incrementing the retry count?

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Is it possible to manually retry a failed service-task with an incident by incrementing the retry count via Camunda cockpit?

Until recently we have used service-tasks as external-tasks. With external-tasks, retry via cockpit works out of the box. Now we are trying to use the java class implementation (`AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior`), which suits our use-case much better, but we haven't yet figured out how to enable retry.

Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

FYI: I've asked the same question in the [Camunda forum](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-to-retry-a-failed-service-task-by-incrementing-the-retry-count/31931).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is definitely possible to retry incidents via cockpit. I am doing it all the time.
I suppose your problem is, that you do not use async continuation ...this is required, otherwise, if an exception occurs the transaction is rolled back and you cannot retry ... if you mark the critical parts of your BPMN as async, you will see the incident in the cockpit and can init a retry.